# while creating the apex class i got this error Unable to build Lightning Component source for markup://c:demo2: Invalid suffix: json

Tags: apex, lightning, component

```
public with sharing class ContactController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact>  getContact(String accId){
        try {
            return [Select AccountId,Id,FirstName from Contact WHERE AccountId:=accId];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you creating this from within the Developer Console, or via an IDE like VS Code? If via an IDE, are you deploying your entire repository?

Answer (score 0):

return [Select AccountId,Id,FirstName from Contact WHERE AccountId=:accId];

replace the colon from := to =: